# TypeError: get_session_auth_hash() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django trying to implement a custom user model but every time i try to log into /admin with it i get two long lists of tracebacks which end in

```python
TypeError: get_session_auth_hash() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

And none of the individual files or calls in the traceback are one of my files

just in case here are my models and backends files

models.py

```python
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user manager
    """
    def create_user(self, username, password):
        if not username or not password:
            raise ValueError("We need username and password here...")
        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        if not username or not password:
            raise ValueError("We need username and password here...")
        user = self.create_user(username=username,password=password)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user class
    """
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Backends.py

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password
from accounts.models import User

class AuthenticationBackend(object):
    """
    Backend for authentication
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return User
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `AuthenticationBackend.get_user`, you have this:

```
        if user.is_active:
            return User
```

which actually returns the `User` **class** instead of your `user` instance. The code calling on this method later tries to call `get_session_auth_hash()` on what you returned, hence your error.

You want:

```
        if user.is_active:
            return user
```

Comment: thankyou i knew it was something small, it just didn't show up

Comment: Hint #1: the error message complained about a missing `self` (first positional) param, which usually means someone tried to call an instance method on a class.  
Hint #2 : in your snippet "User" was highlighted as a class which made the connection obvious ;)